# Regular expression identifier and separator using ':' symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to separate my string between two `':'` characters.

For example, if the input is `"mypage-google-wax:press:-happy"`, then I want `"press"` out.

It can be assumed that the input doesn't contain any numeric characters.

Comment: Why would the output be "Press"? What *exactly* should it do? You talk about "separating" your string, but not what you really mean by that...

Comment: (Tried to clean up the question, not sure if I didn't accidentally change its meaning.)

Answer (score 3):

Any reason to use regular expressions at all, rather than just:

```
string[] bits = text.Split(':');
```

That's assuming I understood your question correctly... which I'm not at all sure about. Anyway, depending on what you really want to do, this *might* be useful to you...

Answer (score 1):

If you're always going to have a string in the format `{stuffIDontWant}:{stuffIWant}:{moreStuffIDontWant}` then `String.Split()` is your answer, not Regex.

To retrieve that middle value, you'd do:

```
string input = "stuffIDontWant:stuffIWant:moreStuffIDontWant"; //get your input
string output = ""; 
string[] parts = input.Split(':'); 
  //converts to an array of strings using the character specified as the separator
output = parts[1]; //assign the second one
return output;
```

Regex is good for patern matching, but, unless you're specifically looking for the word `press`, `String.Split()` is a better answer for this need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in regex:

```
  string pattern = ":([^:]+):";
  string sentence = "some text :data1: some more text :data2: text";
  foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern))
     Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}", 
                       match.Groups[1].Value, match.Index);
```